# Make (user_id&music_id) unique in Likes table and Dislikes table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two base tables in MySQL:

1. users
2. musics

And I have likes and dislikes tables, which contain two fields:

1. user_id
2. music_id

Now, I want to insert a unique item in these two tables. For example, if a user1 likes the music1. The Dislikes table should not allow this user to add a row for music1 to the dislike table.

Is there any way to implement this approach on the SQL side?

Comment: Redesign your db, if logically (user_id music_id) can have only one [dis]like , create only one table with bool rating

Comment: A primary key perhaps?

Comment: You could use triggers. But I would go with Serg's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table like this:

```
music_rate
    - user_id
    -  music_id
    - like(boolean : 1 means like and 0 means dislike)
```

and **check user has like/dislike before store new like/dislike**

Answer (score 4):

You must redesign your database and Merge `likes` and `dislikes` tables and create bool column for rating

OR

you can not redesign database you can use backend languages for check first `table 1` and after check insert to `table 2`

OR SQL way

use [INSERT SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO likes (`music_id`,`user_id`)
SELECT 1, 2
FROM dislikes
WHERE (user_id <> 2 AND  music_id <> 1) 
LIMIT 1
```

use [TRIGGERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dislike_check`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dislike_check` BEFORE INSERT ON `likes` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE dummy integer default 0; 

    SELECT 1 INTO dummy
    FROM dislike
    WHERE (user_id = NEW.user_id AND  music_id = NEW.music_id);

    IF (dummy = 1) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Any Message'; 
    END IF; 
    END
```